# v-show not working with props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to hide or show button using props.

Here is the code

### View (Blade)

```
<product-form-component savebutton="false" updatebutton="false"></product-form-component>
```

### Component template

```
<template>
    <div class="form-actions text-right col-md-12">
                <button v-show="showsavebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button v-show="updatemode && showupdatebutton" class="btn btn- primary">Update</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

### Javascript

```
export default {
        props: ['showupdatebutton', 'showsavebutton', 'modalid']
}
```

Comment: add (:) to props when passing from parent to child:  `:savebutton="false" :updatebutton="false"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points:

- The `props` you are passing don't work the way you think they do; and
- You have to create data variables (or props) in the component with the names you are using in the `v-show`.

## Passing props

When you pass like:

```html
<product-form-component savebutton="false" updatebutton="false"></product-form-component>
```

inside the component, the `savebutton` and `updatebutton` properties will be **strings**. In the example above, they won't be the boolean `false`, they will be the string `"false"`.

To bind them to different values, use `v-bind:propname` or its shorthand `:propname`:

```html
<product-form-component :savebutton="false" :updatebutton="false"></product-form-component>
```

That way, inside the component, those properties will really have the value `false`.

## Variables inside component and `v-show`

The variables you use in the `v-show`s:

```html
<button v-show="showsavebutton" ...
<button v-show="updatemode && showupdatebutton" ...
```

Don't exist in your component. You have to create data variables (or props) in the component with the names you are using in the `v-show`.

Considering you already have some `props` declared, here's an example of declaring those `v-show` variables in the `data()` using the `props` as initial value:

```js
Vue.component('product-form-component', {
  template: "#pfc",
  props: ['updatebutton', 'savebutton', 'modalid'],
  data() {
    return {
      updatemode: this.updatebutton,         // initialized using props
      showupdatebutton: this.updatebutton,
      showsavebutton: this.savebutton
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="pfc">
  <div class="form-actions text-right col-md-12">
    <button v-show="showsavebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button v-show="updatemode && showupdatebutton" class="btn btn- primary">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <product-form-component :savebutton="true" :updatebutton="true"></product-form-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Props as passed down to child with the bind syntax `:`, so in your case you forgot to add it:

try:

```
<product-form-component :savebutton="false" :updatebutton="false"></product-form-component>
```